# PostgreSQL regex_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to convert a string `___abc_[_]xyz` to `...abc.\_xyz` using regular expression.

Is it possible to convert `_` and `[_]` into `.` and `\_` respectively in the same query?

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('___abc_[_]xyz','\[(.)\]','\\\1','g');
```

and

```
SELECT regexp_replace('___abc_[_]xyz','\[_\]','\_','g');
```

The Result of both queries is: `___abc_\_xyz`

Comment: Since you are trying to replace with a hardcoded text, it is not possible without a callback, but PostgreSQL `regexp` functions do not accept callback functions as replacement arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A douible regexp_replace can do the job:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace('___abc_[_]xyz','(?!\[)_(?!\])','.','g'),'\[_\]','\\_','g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 ...abc.\_xyz
(1 row)
```

The first one, using `(?!\[)_(?!\])` will replace underscore NOT in between `[` & `]` with a dot.

The second will replace `[_]` with `\_`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a triple replace:

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace('___abc_[_]xyz','[_]','***MYREPLACE***'),'_','.'),'***MYREPLACE***','\_');
```

1. you replace all `[_]` by a special string that can't exist in your
   string and not containing `_` ( in my example `***MYREPLACE***`)
2. you replace all `_` by `.`
3. you replace all `***MYREPLACE***` by `\_`

Comment: I like this solution best because it is much simpler and faster than using a regular expression.